# Line of best fit with equations

Tags: pgfplots

New to LaTeX, and was hoping someone would be kind enough to give me a hand with trying to draw lines of best fit to these data points. I have included the example I am working on.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{halfcircle}{%
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetfillcolor{white}%
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfplotmarksize}
\pgfusepathqfillstroke
\end{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathmoveto
{\pgfpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}
\pgfpatharc{0}{180}{\pgfplotmarksize}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
}

\begin{filecontents}{conductivity.dat}
L(cm)   50mA    100mA  200mA 400mA 800mA 1000mA
0.0000  0.0000 0.0000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
2.0000  0.0342 0.0635 0.128 0.260 0.520 0.650
3.0000  0.0555 0.1043 0.212 0.423 0.840 1.030
4.0000  0.1104 0.2064 0.396 0.809 1.300 1.700
6.0000  0.1350 0.2426 0.502 1.034 2.010 2.471
7.0000  0.1669 0.3326 0.673 1.339 2.610 3.140

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{conductivity.dat}{\conductivity}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymin = 0,
            xlabel=Bed depth (cm),
            ylabel = Voltage, 
            width=1.2\textwidth,
            height=0.8\textwidth, legend pos={north west},
            xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}]
\addplot+[only marks][black, mark = otimes] table [x={L(cm)}, y={50mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{50mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = star, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={100mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{100mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = o, black ] table [x={L(cm)}, y={200mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{200mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = +, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={400mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{400mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = oplus, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={800mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{800mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark=halfcircle, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={1000mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{1000mA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119179/how-to-add-a-regression-line-to-randomly-generated-points-using-pgfplots-in-tikz/119188?noredirect=1#comment265397_119188 ?

Comment: Thanks Phil, but I'm struggling to incorporate the regression in an  in-line table. Any chance you could try applying it to the example I've provided please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "incorporate the regression in an in-line table". Do you mean that you want to incorporate the equation of the regression line into a LaTeX table? Or do you want to let LaTeX calculate the values of the regression line for the x values in a data table?

Comment: more the latter...have LaTeX calculate and draw the regression line  for the data points plotted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this fit your needs? I added the values of the regression lines for each voltage to the `\conductivity` table with the command `\pgfplotstablecreatecol`. Then you can use easily use those values in plots or use `pgfplotstable` to give you a table containing the values.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% recommended:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{clickable}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{halfcircle}{%
\begin{pgfscope}
\pgfsetfillcolor{white}%
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
{\pgfplotmarksize}
\pgfusepathqfillstroke
\end{pgfscope}%
\pgfpathmoveto
{\pgfpoint{\pgfplotmarksize}{0pt}}
\pgfpatharc{0}{180}{\pgfplotmarksize}
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepathqfill
}

\begin{filecontents}{conductivity.dat}
L(cm)   50mA    100mA  200mA 400mA 800mA 1000mA
0.0000  0.0000 0.0000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
2.0000  0.0342 0.0635 0.128 0.260 0.520 0.650
3.0000  0.0555 0.1043 0.212 0.423 0.840 1.030
4.0000  0.1104 0.2064 0.396 0.809 1.300 1.700
6.0000  0.1350 0.2426 0.502 1.034 2.010 2.471
7.0000  0.1669 0.3326 0.673 1.339 2.610 3.140

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{conductivity.dat}{\conductivity}
% create the `regression' columns:
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=50mA}]{regression 50mA}{\conductivity}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=100mA}]{regression 100mA}{\conductivity}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=200mA}]{regression 200mA}{\conductivity}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=400mA}]{regression 400mA}{\conductivity}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=800mA}]{regression 800mA}{\conductivity}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression={y=1000mA}]{regression 1000mA}{\conductivity}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymin = 0,
            xlabel=Bed depth (cm),
            ylabel = Voltage, 
            width=1.2\textwidth,
            height=0.8\textwidth, legend pos={north west},
            xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}]
% regression
\addplot[black, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 50mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{50mA}
\addplot[orange, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 100mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{100mA}
\addplot[magenta, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 200mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{200mA}
\addplot[green, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 400mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{400mA}
\addplot[blue, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 800mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{800mA}
\addplot[red, no markers] table [x={L(cm)}, y={regression 1000mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{1000mA}
% data 
\addplot+[only marks][black, mark = otimes] table [x={L(cm)}, y={50mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{50mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = star, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={100mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{100mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = o, black ] table [x={L(cm)}, y={200mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{200mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = +, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={400mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{400mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark = oplus, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={800mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{800mA}
\addplot+[only marks] [mark=halfcircle, black] table [x={L(cm)}, y={1000mA}] {\conductivity};\addlegendentry{1000mA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={50mA, 100mA, 200mA, 400mA, 800mA, 1000mA}]\conductivity\\

\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={regression 50mA, regression 100mA, regression 200mA, regression 400mA, regression 800mA}]\conductivity
\end{document}
```