# Confidence band of the regression line in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

In a plot containing experimental data, I have to add a linear regression and the confidence bands of that regression.

Thanks to [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119188/117727) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119179/117727), I was able to get the linear regression but now I wonder how to add the confidence bands.

This produces the expected plot with the linear regression line. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a similar method to add the confidence bands.

In general, the confidence band is given by

[image: equations]

The `t_{\mu,\alpha}` parameter is a tabulated value. For the significance level 0.05 and three value pairs it is 12.70.

#### Current state

```tex
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, columns={x,y}]{
    x;y
    10;1.398e-1
    15;2.196e-1
    20;3.019e-1
    30;4.126e-1
    45;4.904e-1
    70;8.556e-1
    100;9.569e-1
    10;1.293e-1
    15;2.366e-1
    20;2.774e-1
    30;3.848e-1
    45;6.216e-1
    70;7.916e-1
    100;1.079e0
    10;1.265e-1
    15;2.118e-1
    20;2.970e-1
    30;4.882e-1
    45;6.454e-1
    70;8.500e-1
    100;1.287e0
}\loadedtable

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
        ]
        
        \addplot [
            only marks
        ] table {\loadedtable};
        
        \addplot [
            no markers,
            red
        ] table [
            y = {create col/linear regression = {y = y}}
        ] {\loadedtable};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be possible to do all the calculations in TeX, but most likely it will be inefficient. And as long as one is not able to _calculate_ the parameter `t_{\mu,\alpha}` I recommend to calculate the values _externally_ using an appropriate program. You can then either add the values of the confidence interval to your data file or create another data file for this, if you need a higher resolution to get a smoother confidence interval. Then it would remain to plot these data. For that have a look at e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67900.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around, I finally got it working. Below I post my solution in case other users want to add confidence intervals to their `pgfplots` plots too, without having to compute them first using some statistics programs.

Since the calculations require quite a few code lines, which leads to an unreadable document, I divided the code into two files. One file only contains the calculations and can be used for further `pgfplots` by simply importing it. This has the additional advantage that there is only one instance of the code, which dramatically increases the maintainability.

#### Files

**`pgfplots-graphic.tex`**

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfplotstableread[
    col sep = semicolon, 
    columns = {x,y}
]{
    x;y
    10;1.398e-1
    15;2.196e-1
    20;3.019e-1
    30;4.126e-1
    45;4.904e-1
    70;8.556e-1
    100;9.569e-1
    10;1.293e-1
    15;2.366e-1
    20;2.774e-1
    30;3.848e-1
    45;6.216e-1
    70;7.916e-1
    100;1.079e0
    10;1.265e-1
    15;2.118e-1
    20;2.970e-1
    30;4.882e-1
    45;6.454e-1
    70;8.500e-1
    100;1.287e0
}\loadedtable

% Import the calculations
\input{confdence-calculations}

% Value of t-distribution for 95% confidence interval
% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values
\pgfmathsetmacro{\t}{2.093}

% Number of parallel measurements of the real sample
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{3}

\begin{document}
    

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
        ]
        
            % Data points
            \addplot [
                only marks
            ] table {\loadedtable};
            
            % Linear regression
            \addplot [
                domain = 10:100,
                samples = 2,
                red
            ] {\a + \b * x};
            
            % Confidence band
            \addplot [
                domain = 10:100,
                samples = 100
            ] {\a + \b * x + \t * \T * sqrt(1 / \numrows + (x - \xbar)^2 / \Qxx)};
            \addplot [
                domain = 10:100,
                samples = 100
            ] {\a + \b * x - \t * \T * sqrt(1 / \numrows + (x - \xbar)^2 / \Qxx)};
            
            % Tolerance range
            \addplot [
                domain = 10:100,
                samples = 100,
                dashed
            ] {\a + \b * x + \t * \T * sqrt(1 / \m + 1 / \numrows + (x - \xbar)^2 / \Qxx)};
            \addplot [
                domain = 10:100,
                samples = 100,
                dashed
            ] {\a + \b * x - \t * \T * sqrt(1 / \m + 1 / \numrows + (x - \xbar)^2 / \Qxx)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**`confdence-calculations.tex`**

```tex
% Number of samples
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
\edef\numrows{\pgfplotsretval}

% Sum of x-values
\edef\sumx{0}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{x}\of{\loadedtable}\as{\cell}{
    \edef\sumx{\fpeval{\sumx + \cell}}
}

% Sum of y-values
\edef\sumy{0}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{y}\of{\loadedtable}\as{\cell}{
    \edef\sumy{\fpeval{\sumy + \cell}}
}

% Mean value of x
\edef\xbar{\fpeval{\sumx / \numrows}}

% Mean value of y
\edef\ybar{\fpeval{\sumy / \numrows}}

% Calculation of Qxx
\edef\Qxx{0}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numrows-1} {
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{x}\of{\loadedtable}
    
    \edef\Qxx{\fpeval{\Qxx + (\pgfplotsretval - \xbar)^2}}
}

% Calculation of Qyy
\edef\Qyy{0}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numrows-1} {
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{y}\of{\loadedtable}
    
    \edef\Qyy{\fpeval{\Qyy + (\pgfplotsretval - \ybar)^2}}
}

% Calculation of Rxy
\edef\Rxy{0}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0,...,\numrows-1} {
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{x}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\currx}{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{y}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\curry}{\pgfplotsretval}
    
    \edef\Rxy{\fpeval{\Rxy + (\currx - \xbar)(\curry - \ybar)}}
}

% Calculation of the residual standard deviation T
\edef\T{\fpeval{sqrt((\Qyy - (\Rxy^2 / \Qxx)) / (\numrows - 2))}}

% Calculation of the slope b
\edef\b{\fpeval{\Rxy/\Qxx}}

% Calculation of the ordinate intercept
\edef\a{\fpeval{\ybar - \b * \xbar}}
```

[image: Resulting graphic]